# mod_rewrite on the same server but different website

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have 2 websites on a server located in the following folders:

- /var/www/site1.com/
- /var/www/site2.com/

There is a folder 'test' on 2nd site with php-scripts inside:

- /var/www/site2.com/test/

So these scripts could be accessed via http this way:

- http://site2.com/test/script.php

I need these scripts to be also access via 1st domain, like this:

- http://site1.com/test/script.php

BUT without copying these files to site1's folder

is this possible using mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a symlink to your test folder.

```
ln -s /var/www/site1.com/test /var/www/site2.com/test
```

If you have  the `+FollowSymLinks` option in your apache configuration for that vhost, I guess that should work.